# Custom groovy script is not getting invoke for DBAT trusted Incremental reconciliation

Tags: groovy, identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I have **D**ata**B**ase **A**pplication **T**able(DBAT) connector installed on OIM11gR2PS3 box. We have custom groovy script in place for Incremental Reconciliation scheduler, but even having just sysout statements in groovy, the script is not getting invoked.

I checked the Connector configuration lookup the values for groovy file is correctly configured as below:

```
code: syncScript  decode: file:///URL
```

The oim_server1-dignostic.log file show below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ADP ClassLoader failed to load: Script1
```

Any help at earliest would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (not very clear) is in

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22999_01/doc.111/e20277/intro.htm#CHDDBGBA.

You need to:

1. download the connector software (which I think is what you mean when you say its 'installed')
2. amend resources/DBATConfiguration.groovy as required
3. run the bin/DBATGenerator.cmd or sh to generate the connector
4. install the resulting connector in OIM via the sysadmin console.

Once the connector has been generated, I don't think the groovy file has any further use.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the read from file flag.

syncScript[LOADFROMURL]

Comment: I have tried this but still groovy is not getting executed,